# Why won't my ice maker shut off?

Tags: repair, refrigerator, ice-maker

My ice maker won't shut off and leaks all over the freezer.  This is seriously maddening since I then have to unplug my refrigerator every week for a 24 hour period to defrost the ice on the bottom of my freezer.  I then chip at it until I can pull out the sheet of ice and start over for another week.

Any suggestions besides getting a new refrigerator?

Comment: Most have a little arm that is raised as the ice level increases.  Is this working?  Check the arm, the switch, and the valve it controls - one may be broken.  Or the water line may have a leak in it.

Comment: Including the make and model of the appliance will help others provide more accurate information.

Answer (score 1):

The leakage all over the freezer sounds like a bad solenoid valve on the water line. At least on my freezer it's located near where the water comes in, and is not too difficult to replace. There's probably a 'how to' page somewhere on the internet for your particular model.